# Download all files on a click event

Tags: python

```
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/acer/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
url = 'http://biokb.ncpsb.org/AllerGAtlas/index.php/Home/Browse/?fbclid=IwAR2RPwrnsT7zR9SEdU0PW-eJ7HAelg6WRyn23-hCjTrNCEOb1uOMd_qG3ns'
webdriver.get(url)
webdriver.save_screenshot('test.png')
webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('fa fa-download').click()
#webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="fa fa-download"]').click()
```

I want to download all the files available.

The error I got :

> InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted
>   (Session info: headless chrome = 73.0.3683.103)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver = 2.45.615291 
>   (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387), platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid .click and concatenate the name onto base url and .get which will download all. Specify path to chromedriver if not on environmental path.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

base = 'http://biokb.ncpsb.org/AllerGAtlas/index.php/Home/Download/gene/genesymbol/'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('http://biokb.ncpsb.org/AllerGAtlas/index.php/Home/Browse/?fbclid=IwAR2RPwrnsT7zR9SEdU0PW-eJ7HAelg6WRyn23-hCjTrNCEOb1uOMd_qG3ns')
links = [base + item.text for item in  WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#geneTable td:nth-of-type(1)")))]
for link in links:
    d.get(link)
d.quit()
```

Comment: Has something changed with this? It works doesn't it?

Comment: It does not work. The code returns me no matching error.

Comment: I just ran it perfectly now. What is the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `find_elements` which will return a list of web element. 
You can not invoke `click()` method on it.

`click()` method is for web element.

instead try this code :

```
all_links = webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('fa fa-download')
for link in all_links:
  link.click()
```

Comment: There are no errors, but the download does not start.

Answer (score 0):

```
webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('fa fa-download').click()
```

Please note `find_elements` returns list so you should use `find_element` instead.
However when you use `find_element_by_class_name` you can't provide mutliple class name which gives you error as you can see your error message.so try follwoing code.

```
webdriver.find_element_by_class_name('fa-download').click()
```

OR

```
webdriver.find_elements_by_class_name('fa-download')[0].click()
```

OR you can use css selector.

```
webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.fa.fa-download')[0].click()
```

**EDITED**

Try induce webdriverwait to identify element and then clicks either options.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By   

elements=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.fa.fa-download')))

elements[0].click()
```

OR

```
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.fa.fa-download')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elements[0]).click().perform()
```

Comment: There are no errors, but the download does not start.

Comment: @Jena : check the Edited sections

Comment: I got timeout exception error TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: since i don't have access of the application don't know class name you have provided is right.Can you post html where you are accessing the download link?